# How can I see Debug.Print() statements?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, debug

I tried to analyze a macro by adding debug output to it. The shortest test code would be

```
Sub Macro1()
    Debug.Print ("Hello World")
End Sub
```

I have tried showing additional Windows in Word, but I could not find a "Debug output" or even "Output" window like I know from Visual Studio.

I also tried running [SysInternals DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx), but the output does not appear there.

How can I see the output of such a `Debug.Print` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output appears in the "Immediate" window. It can be shown in Word 2010 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or from the menu View / Immediate Window.

[image: Immediate window]